# How to use AngularDart ng-repeat over a list of simple values possibly with duplicates

Tags: dart, angular-dart

The AngularDart `ng-repeat` directive seems to require unique values; e.g., the following

```html
  <li ng-repeat="x in ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice']">...</li>
```

results in

```
  [NgErr50] ngRepeat error! Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. 
  Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.
```

Assuming that the list of strings is obtained from some external source and that uniqueness of values is not guaranteed, how can the `[NgErr50]` be avoided?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-repeat not working over collections that contains dupes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452223/ng-repeat-not-working-over-collections-that-contains-dupes)

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```html
  <li ng-repeat="x in ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice'] track by $index">...</li>
```

For more options, see the [ng-repeat API docs](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular.NgRepeatDirective).