# Nested array ng-repeat error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Tags: angularjs

I have an object I'm trying to iterate through and having trouble nesting the `ng-repeats`

```
$scope.report_data = {
  data [
    system_0: [
      0: "string",
      1: 435,
      2: "another value"
    ]
  ], 
  headers [
    0: [
      0:"title"
      1: "CHA"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to build a table with the headers as th's and each piece of data is mapped to the headers.

What I have right now is

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="header in report_data.headers">{{ header.0 }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="system in report_data.data">
        <span ng-repeat="_item in system">{{ _item }}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

But I'm not able to iterate over each item in each system and add it as a column. The error I'm receiving is `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]`

What's the best way to iterate over nested arrays?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular ng-repeat Error "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed)

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452223/ng-repeat-not-working-over-collections-that-contains-dupes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152576/ngrepeatdupes-duplicates-in-repeater-with-nested-ngrepeat-and-empty-strings/26152601#26152601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) uses a hash of the entire object to track insertions/deletions by in order to make optimize DOM manipulation. T**his has to be unique or else it will fail.**

So two objects with the same properties and values will collide.

You can be explicit about what property to track using the `track by` syntax, but again, this must be unique.

As a last resort you can use `track by $index` to get around having duplicate entries.

```
ng-repeat="widget in widgets track by $index"
```